# SUMIF Value is Greater Than Value in Previous Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Is there a way to use SUMIF to sum values in a column when they are greater than the value in the same row in the previous column?  [ie the sum of B2, B4, and B6 in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oLWT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$6>$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$6))
```

Be sure to press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when you exit cell edit mode instead of only `Enter`

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds!

Comment: I beat @Kyle by 9 seconds!

Comment: That is a really obvious solution.  I had initially tried almost the same thing, but with =SUMIF() instead of =SUM(IF()), which just results in an error.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that happens to me so often! I need to learn to type faster :)

Comment: @Kyle - it all depends on when you see the question as well, and how quickly the solution comes to you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array because I'm too lazy to figure out a non-array solution:

```
{=SUM(If(B:B>A:A,B:B,0))}
```

Limit the ranges as necessary to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

The main focus here is to don't hardcode each cell...

This can be achieved by:

1. Using a combination of sum and if in an array operation

   `{=SUM(IF(B:B>A:A;1;0))}`

OR

2. Creating another column and performing a sum:

In column C put this function in each row:

```
=IF(B2>A2;B2;0)
```

Then on a single cell (lets say `D2`), place this formula:

```
=SUM(C:C)
```

I.e.:

[image: table1]